# can't understand this bash script $ awk -F

Tags: csv, awk

Can someone help me understand what these scripts mean?

```
$ awk -F',' '{  data[$4]+=$29;}END{c=0; for (i in data) { if (data[i]+0<1000000) {c++}} ;print c}'  file.csv
```

thanks

Comment: How about learning and reading about `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scripts iterates line by line over the input file `file.csv`. The file is apparently separated by comma (,), thus the field separator is set via `-F','` appropriately. Then you access the `data` array with the content of the 4th field (`$4`) and add the value of the 29th field (`$29`). After processing all lines, at the end, `END` code section is invoked. It iterates over your data array, does some numerical comparison and eventually prints the number of times  `c` the numerical comparison evaluated to true.